# Magento - Backend error after deleting store view

Tags: magento

I deleted a store view in the Magento Backend and since then I see this message in the backend:

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 163892354656

The log file reads:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Invalid website id requested.";i:1;s:3722:"#0 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(950): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid website...')
#1 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(469): Mage_Core_Model_App->getWebsite('3')
#2 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(150): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getWebsite()
#3 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/tax/notifications.phtml(31): Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getWebsitesWithWrongDiscountSettings()
#4 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/web18/...')
#5 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(196): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
#10 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#14 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#15 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/web18/...')
#16 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#17 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#24 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#25 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /var/www/web18/html/hamburg/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:78:"/hamburg/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/070d52ebdc1203106f8d2f782024de19/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/hamburg/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

How can I fix this? In the database table core_store I see:

```
store_id,code,website_id,group_id,name,sort_order,is_active
    0,"admin","0","0","Admin","0","1"
    2,"german","1","1","German","0","1"
    4,"english1","3","2","English","1","1"
    5,"french1","3","2","French","2","1"
    6,"hellog","2","3","English","1","1"
    8,"english3","2","4","English","1","1"
    9,"french3","2","4","French","2","1"
    10,"english4","1","5","English","1","1"
    11,"french4","1","5","French","2","1"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you perform indexing or clear cache ?

Comment: I cannot access the magento admin... @user3793635

Comment: Try to clear cache by folder var/cache and indexing by command

Comment: And if I can't access the server via command line? @user3793635

Comment: go to mysql type "show processlist" and kill the processes

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. From where does the script take the website id = 3. Website ID 3 must be set up in the database as the current main store view...but where can I find it?